# Having trouble locating an element hidden behind an iFrame

Tags: typescript, iframe, playwright

Im trying to validate when something appears but its behind an iFrame

```
  const frame = this.page.frameLocator('#viewer');
        console.log(frame);
        const elementWithinFrame = frame.locator('#viewerList');
        await expect(elementWithinFrame).toBeVisible({timeout:10000});
```

When the log appears in the console after the test is ran I can confirm it is able to detect the frame and display it inside of the console using the ID im passing, but when I attempt to locate the element within the frame Im not able to find anything, I can confirm the ID for the element im attempting to validate is visible, is correct.

I know frameLocator has some specific functions I can try like getByRole, getByText, getByTestId, etc but in this case I don't believe any of those will work.

Is there anyway I can use the elements ID or write up a custom xPath and pass that along instead?

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of the page you're automating.